# Value is not found in boundfield in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hiddenfield

I am trying to assing value to hiddenfield on indexchange event of dropdownlist ! Actually the problem is when I am trying to update my record i can not find value of that hidden field ! Kindly give me solution or suggest any another option ! Thank You !

My grid view is

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LocCode" SortExpression="LocCode">
   <EditItemTemplate>
       <ajax:UpdatePanel ID="upEditsLocation" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
           <ContentTemplate>
              <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLocation" runat="server" 
                 DataSourceID="sdsLocation" 
                 OnDataBound="ddlLocation_DataBound"  
                 DataValueField="LocCode" AppendDataBoundItems="false" 
                 DataTextField="LocCode" 
                 AutoPostBack="true" 
                 onselectedindexchanged="ddlLocation_SelectedIndexChanged">
              </asp:DropDownList>
              <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsLocation" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ccConnString %>"
                 ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CCConnString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="Select LocCode from Location">
              </asp:SqlDataSource>
           </ContentTemplate>
       </ajax:UpdatePanel>
   </EditItemTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="lblLocation" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LocCode") %>'>
       </asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and my indexchange event is

```
protected void  ddlLocation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hdloc.Value = ddlLocation.SelectedItem.Text;

}
```

And my hidden field is

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdloc" runat="server" />
```

Comment: where is that hidden field placed? outside your data binding control?

Comment: yes ! But value assign to hidden field but i can not access it to code behind ! I don't know the actual problem when i trying to access it it gives null !

Comment: what can't you access hdloc or ddlLocation ?

Answer (score 0):

From the code I can see the `HiddenField` is not part of your update panel. Hence if you assign any value to it, it will not reflect on client machine. Increase the scope of panel to include the hidden field, and then try.

OR you can try [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1426442.aspx/1) solution from ASP.net Forum

[Here is a small tutorial on update panel (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bb399001.aspx)

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
GridViewRow cancel = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
Label lbldeleteID = (Label)cancel.FindControl("lblid");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't access hdloc from code behind, either is not added by Visual Studio on aspx.designer.cs (try delete it and add it back or change the id and then back to original value) or the hidden field is placed in other template of another binding control, which means you need to use ctrl.FindControl("hdloc") then cast to HiddenField.

Also you need to place this hidden field into an UpdatePanel with UpdateMode="Always".

```
protected void  ddlLocation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    hdloc.Value = (sender as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

I'm sure that ddlLocation.SelectedItem.Text, like you use it, it gives a compilation error, because ddlLocation is not visible on code behind, since is inside of EditItemTemplate.